# yii2 labelEx of ActiveForm

Tags: label, yii2, active-form

in old Yii I was using

```
    <?php  echo $form->labelEx($model,'text').'<span class="required">* </span>'); ?>
```

What should I use in yii2 for labeling ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Yii2`'s way is like below:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fieldName')->label('Label Of FieldName'); ?>
```

So yours would be something like below:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->label('Text'. Html::tag('span', '*',['class'=>'required'])); ?>
```

Please note that you need to add `use yii\helpers\Html;` in your View. Otherwise, you need to replace `Html::` with `yii\helpers\Html::`.

---

**Update**

For those who suffer from `required` css class added automatically to parent `DIV` of a form field:

You can remove it like below:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['requiredCssClass' => '' ...
```

Please note that, this applies to your whole form. So whole form has no required `css` class. You need to write it for each field by yourself.

Comment: So as I can see we label input fields inside the string of input declaration yes? I mean in old yii I was writing label string then input field string. Now I must do it together.

Comment: One small problem. The way you attached span to 'Text' it applies it's class to the Text also. Is there way to fix it ?

Comment: Hi dear, are you sure that it attaches the required class to the text? I can see it generates `Text<span class="required">*</span>`.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right in that string everything is ok, problem is a bit different. that Label creates div with 'required' attribute
<div class="form-group field-someData-domeDataID required">
Why this happens ?

Comment: Yii automatically puts that. As in source code we have: `if ($this->model->isAttributeRequired($attribute)) {
            $class[] = $this->form->requiredCssClass;
        }`. If attribute is required it puts a required class to the field.

Comment: Then the whole thing loses sense, but anyway thanks for help. I'll just use something different to label my inputs

Comment: Ali MasudianPour Thank you

Comment: but this will wrap the `span` inside the `label` tag rather than replacing the `label` tag with `span`, isnt it ?.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this in css instead of modifying code.

```
div.required label:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

That was discussed here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2056

Comment: Perfect answer. This answer should have been accepted.